# calculate p value for ROC AUC by subgroups

Tags: sas, roc, auc

I'm trying to see if there is a statistically significant difference in ROC AUC by subgroups in SAS. I can't use roccontrast because I only have one model. Here is my codes:

```
 proc logistic data=data plots(only)=roc;
         by Race;
         model htn (event='1') = bmi ;
         ods output roccurve=ROCdata;
         run;
```

Race has 4 categories: hispanic, black, white and other

I tried roccontrast, didn't work. I would really appreciate any guidance on this!

Comment: Please see this question and documentation referenced in example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261602/sas-how-to-make-two-roc-curve-of-two-comparison-groups-on-the-same-plot

Answer (score 0):

`roccontrast` in SAS cannot be used as it requires multiple models for comparison, as you are now aware. However, you can still perform a comparison of ROC curves by subgroup using a similar approach to the one described in the [answer linked to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261602/sas-how-to-make-two-roc-curve-of-two-comparison-groups-on-the-same-plot):

Run `PROC LOGISTIC` with `BY` Statement: You've already done this part. By using the `BY` statement, you run the logistic regression separately for each subgroup (hispanic, black, white, and other). The ODS OUTPUT roccurve=ROCdata; will capture the necessary ROC statistics for each subgroup.

To visually compare the ROC curves for each subgroup, use the `SGPLOT` procedure on the ROCdata. This will help you see how the ROC curves differ across the subgroups.

```
proc sgplot data=ROCdata;
    series x=1-Specificity y=Sensitivity / group=Race;
    xaxis label="1-Specificity";
    yaxis label="Sensitivity";
    title "ROC Curves by Race";
run;
```

To statistically compare the AUCs between subgroups, you will need to compute a test statistic. This involves a pairwise comparison of AUCs, taking into account their standard errors. You can compute the standard errors of the AUCs from the ROCdata output and then perform a Z-test for each pair of subgroups.

F9or the Data Step, the comparison involves calculating the Z-score for the difference in AUCs between each pair of subgroups. Here's a generalised approach:

```
data pairwise_comparison;
    set ROCdata;
    /* Assuming ROCdata has variables Race, AUC, and AUC_SE for each race category */
    array races[4] $ hispanic black white other; /* Update with exact variable names */
    array auc[4] hispanic_auc black_auc white_auc other_auc; /* AUCs */
    array auc_se[4] hispanic_auc_se black_auc_se white_auc_se other_auc_se; /* Standard errors */

    do i = 1 to 4;
        do j = i+1 to 4;
            race1 = races[i];
            race2 = races[j];
            auc_diff = auc[i] - auc[j];
            se_diff = sqrt(auc_se[i]**2 + auc_se[j]**2);
            z = auc_diff / se_diff;
            p_value = (1 - probnorm(abs(z))) * 2; /* two-tailed test */
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

The pairwise_comparison dataset will contain the Z-scores and p-values for each pair of subgroups.